# How to disable third party repositories? I have tried sudo software-properties-gtk but it does not work

Tags: software-installation, software-center, update-manager

I cannot seem to find a way to disable third party repositories.

I need to do this to update from 14.04 to 14.10

I type

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

But all I get is this

```
alex@alex-NV55C:~$ sudo software-properties-gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 101, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 98, in __init__
    SoftwareProperties.__init__(self, options=options, datadir=datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.sourceslist = SourcesList()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 274, in __init__
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 459, in __init__
    dist = DistInfo(f, base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 186, in __init__
    for line in dist_file:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0):

The graphical way to remove repositories is:

- System Settings -> Software & Updates.  Go to the "Other Software" tab.  I'm guessing you will want to uncheck everything on that list, but at least the "Independent" repo.
- You can get to the same screen by running `sudo software-properties-gtk`, as you tried.  That is a python traceback, but I do not know what would cause that error.

You can also remove repositories from the command line:

- `sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu'`

As to why software-properties-gtk will not run, it seems this might be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1053749).  It looks like editing `/var/lib/dpkg/status` to remove funny characters might fix the issue (as mentioned in, e.g., comment 19 of that link).  The problem seems to be that information about some package in /var/lib/dpkg/status does not valid UTF-8 encoding, and this causes the crash.

Comment: I click on the the software and updates and it wont even open up after clicking on it multiple times. What now, am I screwed?

Comment: hmmm... there is a way to do this from the command line.  I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate you helping me out when you dont have to.